# Upload file with Fetch API in Javascript and show progress

Tags: javascript, upload, fetch-api

I'm using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in Javascript to upload big file to server. Is there any event in Fetch API that I could use to track progress of upload?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is **NOT** possible. The reason is the way the Fetch API works.

The `fetch` method returns a Promise; the Promise API uses a `then` method to which you can attach “success” and “failure” callbacks. Therefore, you can gain access to progress.

Still, don't lose hope! There is a workaround that can do the trick (I found it on [github](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/89) repository of the Fetch API):

you can convert the request to a stream request and then when a response return is just a bitarray of the file content. then you need to collect all of the data and when its end decode it to the file you want

```
function consume(stream, total = 0) {
  while (stream.state === "readable") {
    var data = stream.read()
    total += data.byteLength;
    console.log("received " + data.byteLength + " bytes (" + total + " bytes in total).")
  }
  if (stream.state === "waiting") {
    stream.ready.then(() => consume(stream, total))
  }
  return stream.closed
}
fetch("/music/pk/altes-kamuffel.flac")
  .then(res => consume(res.body))
  .then(() => console.log("consumed the entire body without keeping the whole thing in memory!"))
  .catch((e) => console.error("something went wrong", e))
```

Comment: You forget to mention that the response should be stream otherwise it won't work: From the git comment:
`...and you'll also be able to provide a readable stream when creating responses too. Streams everywhere`

Comment: Can someone clarify? This answer seems to track progress of a download, not an upload.

Comment: Yes, doesn't this track download instead of upload? Or is it like a ping pong of chunks of bytes between the server and the client where the server (as soon as it receives a new chunk of bytes) sends the received chunk back to the client so that the client knows that the server has received the chunk it previously sent?