# Fetch API Download Progress Indicator?

Tags: javascript, download, stream, progress-bar, fetch-api

I am trying to capture the download progress of a Fetch request and use that to change the width of a progress bar. I looked at ProgressEvent.lengthComputable as a potential solution but unsure if this can be used with the Fetch API.

Comment: Not true. The promise from a fetch() resolves after the first packet has been received, but doesn't wait until the whole body is there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453950/upload-file-with-fetch-api-in-javascript-and-show-progress

Comment: then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/progress-indicators-for-fetch would be better besides it's older

Comment: Can't flag as duplicate because of the bounty, but it's all there.

Comment: Adriani6 Touffy thanks a lot for that information

Comment: Let's reopen because this question is download specific, and the suggested duplicate answer is upload-specific

Answer (score 25):

without checking for errors (as in try/catch etc...)

```js
const elStatus = document.getElementById('status');
function status(text) {
  elStatus.innerHTML = text;
}

const elProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
function progress({loaded, total}) {
  elProgress.innerHTML = Math.round(loaded/total*100)+'%';
}

async function main() {
  status('downloading with fetch()...');
  const response = await fetch('https://fetch-progress.anthum.com/30kbps/images/sunrise-baseline.jpg');
  const contentLength = response.headers.get('content-length');
  const total = parseInt(contentLength, 10);
  let loaded = 0;

  const res = new Response(new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      for (;;) {
        const {done, value} = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        loaded += value.byteLength;
        progress({loaded, total})
        controller.enqueue(value);
      }
      controller.close();
    },
  }));
  const blob = await res.blob();
  status('download completed')
  document.getElementById('img').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

main();
```

```html
<div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
<h1 id="progress">&nbsp;</h1>
<img id="img" />
```

adapted from [here](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators)

Comment: This doesn't work if the server sends compressed encoded response. For example gzip compressed. Say the client sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header, and server responds with - `Content-Type: application/json` `Content-Encoding: gzip` `Content-Length: xxx`

then the length `xxx` will much smaller than the total length of chunks while reading from the body reader. Basically `loaded` will be more than `total` after a certain point. Because the `content-length` header contains the size of the compressed response. But `loaded` is the chunk size calculated after decompressing.

Comment: Apparently you're out of luck for compressed stuff period. There's no standard header that sends the size of the compressed data. If you control the server you could send a custom header with that info.

Comment: **Progress incorrect when content is gzip encoded**: https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/issues/13 / **Incorrect progress for gzip encoded response**: https://github.com/samundrak/fetch-progress/issues/22

Answer (score 5):

Using this utility:

```js
async function* streamToAsyncIterable(stream) {
  const reader = stream.getReader()
  try {
    while (true) {
      const {done, value} = await reader.read()
      if (done) return
      yield value
    }
  } finally {
    reader.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

<sup>See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_generators</sup>

Then you can use `for await...of` loop:

```js
const response = await fetch(url)
let responseSize = 0
for await (const chunk of streamToAsyncIterable(response.body)) responseSize += chunk.length
```

---

*IMPORTANT*

But be aware that `responseSize` is **response-size**! Not necessarily **download-size** (`content-length`)!

*What is the difference?*

There is no difference if there is no `content-encoding` (`gzip`, `br`, ...). But if a comperession was applied, **download-size** will be the size of *compressed data* (the same `content-length`), and **response-size** will be the size of *uncompressed data*.

See @ecthiender [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285198/fetch-api-download-progress-indicator#comment125811933_64123890) and [this thread](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/issues/13#issuecomment-622196688).

---

More verbose example with resolving the full response:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/72903731/5318303
let responseSize = 0 // `responseSize` is response-size! Not necessarily download-size ('content-length')! See the above link.
const chunks = []
const asyncIterable = streamToAsyncIterable(res.body)

for await (const chunk of streamToAsyncIterable(res.body)) {
  responseSize += chunk.length
  console.log(`${responseSize.toLocaleString('en-US')} decompressed bytes received.`)
  chunks.push(chunk)
}

const bytes = new Uint8Array(responseSize)
let offset = 0
for (const chunk of chunks) {
  bytes.set(chunk, offset) // `chunk` is a `Uint8Array`
  offset += chunk.length
}
const resBody = new TextDecoder().decode(bytes)
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer. I have one issue. I tried to call foo = await response.json() after and it failed because the body stream already read. is there a way to get the json from the response at the end?

Comment: @dooderson; AFAIK, in that case, you need to do that manually. I mean you need to read (and concatenate) `totalBytes` (in the same `for await` loop). Then you need to convert `totalBytes` to `string`  and then `JSON.parse()` it. Don't convert every `chunk` to `string` (then concatente `string`s)! This causes some issues with multi-byte characters that may be placed at the boundaries of two sequent chunks.

Answer (score -5):

you can use axios instead

```
import axios from 'axios'
export async function uploadFile(file, cb) {
  const url = `//127.0.0.1:4000/profile`
  try {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("avatar", file)
    const data = await axios.post(url, formData, {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        console.log(progressEvent)
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
          let percentComplete = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total;
          if (cb) {
            cb(percentComplete)
          }
        }
      }
    })
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Specifically asked for FETCH and not xmlHTTP !